# How do I make this airy pad sound?

Tags: synthesizer

At the beginning of this track, it starts with an amazing airy pad, which I have no idea how to design.

I have sylenth, spire, serum and vps avenger,

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest how I could build it in any of those synths :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the very beginning pulsing pad?

To me it sounds like is a saw and maybe synth string pad with a cutoff filter set low.